# Prevent div filling parent table cell

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment

I've checked a few similar answers but can't find anything that works. I want to align each of the yellow divs vertically inside a table cell without filling it's parent div.

I've tried `overflow:hidden` and can't use `display:inline-block`

Am sure this is an easy one!

Thanks

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/alidrongo/cf9fxnyy/)

Comment: You need to specify their size if you don't want them to assume `100%` width and height. And a table-cell display is designed to fill the container.

Comment: Thanks @Jdsfighter I want the size of each to match the text that is contained within.

Comment: You can't do that if `.mobile-button` class has the `display: table-cell;` property, because you are saying that it has to fill

Comment: Why not change `display: table-cell;` to `display:initial;` within the `.mobile-child` selector? This will make the background match the size of the text.

Comment: You would have to wrap the text in a span for that I suspect. Text should be in a textual element anyway rather than bare text nodes in a div IMO.

Comment: hmm @Jdsfighter If I change it within `mobile-button` (which I think is what you mean) that works great for the widths but the divs are no longer vertically centred within their parent.

Comment: Just add another div? https://jsfiddle.net/cf9fxnyy/48/

Comment: That works great @Pete do you know how I can keep the divs the same width as the text they contain as well?

Comment: Change them to a span: https://jsfiddle.net/cf9fxnyy/50/, unfortunately though, if you want to add padding to the yellow, then you will need to make the span inline-block (which you said you didn't want to do)

Comment: If you need padding (without `inline-block`), then using `display:flex` will be the way to go: https://jsfiddle.net/cf9fxnyy/54/

Comment: Thanks @Pete thats it! Much appreciated.